# Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 134217728 bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)

Tags: apache, memory, centos

Good morning, this is what i get from apache error

```
Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 134217728 bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)
```

This is my ipcs -lm

```
------ Limiti della memoria condivisa --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 131072
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 536870912
dimensione min seg (byte) = 1
```

This is cat /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
# kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
# kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
# kernel.shmmax = 200000000

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
# kernel.shmall = 50000
#
```

I've set unlimit to unlimited, and i've tryed all the things present on internet.

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: When are you getting that error ? While in load ?

Comment: I Get 500error sometimes in my PHP app, and i get this error in error_log of apache

Answer (score 0):

first of all,
please consider to remove # sign before

```
# kernel.shmmax = 200000000
# kernel.shmall = 50000
```

like this:

```
# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 200000000

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 50000
```